# flexigrid select row by selectedIndex

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

i need help, how to trSelected by index on flexigrid?

```
$("#myTable td").prop("selectedIndex",3).addClass("trSelected")
```

not working

Comment: How are you calling this code? What's your HTML look like? What do you expect to happen? What have you already done to try and resolve the issue? So many unanswered questions... Please update your question so that it shows **all** of your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and **clearly** state your expected behaviour and what is not happening. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

At the first, please add your code for more information.

in Jquery, you can use `:nth-child(n|even|odd|formula)` if you are going to implement index searching.

For example:

```
$("#myTable td selectedIndex:nth-child(3)");
```

Above code get the third child of `myTable -> td -> selectedIndex` (The first element has the index number 1)